# TouchableOpacity link to another page and pass data React Native

Tags: react-native

Hi i am hitting to a problem. In the Homepage, I am creating a list of cards where show name, amount, and image, and those cards are created by another function from  InfoCard.js.

Now I am not sure how to **pass** the data ( name, amount) and **link** to another page

Homepage:

```
import InfoCard from "../components/test";

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
return (      
    {data.map((item, index) => (
      <InfoCard {...item} key={index} />
    ))}      
 );
};
export default Home;
```

InfoCard js

```
export default InfoCard = ({ image, brand, amount }) => {
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Detail")}>
 <View style={externalStyle.home_company_list}>
   <Image source={image} />
   <View style={externalStyle.card}>
     <Text style={externalStyle.home_company_text}>{brand}</Text>
     <Text style={externalStyle.home_company_text}>{amount}</Text>
   </View>
 </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
);
};
```

Detail Page

Once the TouchableOpacity clicked from home page which created by InFoCard.js, will pass the data(brand,amount) to Detail page and display the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it as params:

```
export default InfoCard = ({ image, brand, amount }) => {
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Detail", {brand: brand,
amount: amount,})}>
 <View style={externalStyle.home_company_list}>
   <Image source={image} />
   <View style={externalStyle.card}>
     <Text style={externalStyle.home_company_text}>{brand}</Text>
     <Text style={externalStyle.home_company_text}>{amount}</Text>
   </View>
 </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
);
};
```

And get it in details as:

this.props.navigation.state.params.brand,
this.props.navigation.state.params.amount

Comment: thanks, and so close but I got it fixed. so I need to pass the navigation in the parameter, then in the Detail page receive { navigation, route }, then access the data from the route like "route.params.amount"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the parameter after the "Detail" Route name.
Take a look here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/